# How to work on Tab view in MVC 4 ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, tabview

I am new one for ASP.NET.
I want to list out my views in TabView.

I do the Following Changes in my application,

In _Layout.cshtml i add the following bundle in

```
<head>
      @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css") 
</head>
```

and

```
<Body>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui") 
<Body>
```

After that i add two controller like Default1 and Default2, in both controller i add one view like, index.

Then i write the following code in **Index.cshtml** in **Home view** to display my controller view in particular tab like.

```
<div id="body">
<div id="tabs">

<ul>
  <li><a href="/Default1/Index">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Default2/Index">Tab 2</a></li>

</ul>
  @section scripts
{
<script>


        $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
        });



</script>
}
</div>
</div>
```

But it's not working. I don't Know i add more code for work that.

Please help me. Thanks in advancce.

Comment: And if you navigate manually to `/Default1/Index` it returns the content you expect?

Comment: Yes manual navigation was working.........

Comment: Other things to check: Is `$(function() {...` definately being called? What about if you add `alert('test')` or `console.log('test')`, does this get output? If it is being called, is jQueryUI definately loaded? If you alert/log `$('#tabs').tabs` in `$(function` do you get a function definition or undefined?

Comment: At first time only alert came... TabView was working.... but i click next tab it's not working.. at the same time i click the reload button in browser that time display the Content of controller

Comment: Sounds like the tabs are initialising ok, but then for some reason clicking the tab is navigating to the link rather than switching tabs. Can't help you any further unfortunately

Comment: One more thing to check - is the content of each tab being rendered as a Partial? It's not pulling in a full page is it?

Comment: does your bundle extract jqueryui scripts on client side...

Answer (score 1):

You have to add content also to display on tab click .so add two div in your code .as shown below.

Modified code ::

```
     <div id="body">
     <div id="tabs">

     <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>

         </ul>
         @section scripts
      {
         <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });

     </script>
         }
      </div>

         <div id="tab-1"> 
        'content which you want to display on click of first tab'

       </div>
     <div id="tab-2">

             'content which you want to display on click of second tab'
             </div>
             </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it will fix all your issues but this:

```
$(function () {

    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });

});
```

should be:

```
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

You don't need 2 `$(function() {})` handlers